# Choose and sort data with different queries

Tags: php, mysql

Example, in test.php, if user choose `$period = 'current'` and `$sort = earliest`, only the data that is in the current month  will be shown. The `order(sort)` will be from earliest to latest shown on `dotest.php`. How do I this on a table? How do I call out the specific data chosen?

In `test.php`,

```
                <tr> 
                    <td class="alt"><label for="period"><b>Transaction Period:</b> </label></td>
                    <td><input type="radio" name="period" value="current">Current Month<br>
                        <input type="radio" name="period" value="current_first">Last 1 Month and Current Month<br>
                        <input type="radio" name="period" value="current_second">Last 2 Months and Current Month</td>          
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="alt"><label for="sort"><b>Sort According To: </b></label></td>
                    <td> 
<select name="sort">
                        <option value="latest">Latest Transaction First</option>
                        <option value="earliest">Earliest Transaction First</option>
                          <option value="codes">Transaction Codes</option>
                          <option value="credit">Credit Only</option>
                          <option value="debit">Debit Only</option>
                        </select>
</td>        
                </tr>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"></input>
```

In `dotest.php`,

```
     <?php
    $period = $_POST['period'];
    $sort = $_POST['sort'];


                    if ($period == 'current'){
                        $query1 = "SELECT * FROM transaction WHERE account_id ='$acc_id' AND user_id= '$user_id' AND MONTH(CURDATE())= MONTH(date)";
                    }
                    elseif ($period == 'current_first'){
                        $query1 = "SELECT * FROM transaction WHERE account_id ='$acc_id' AND user_id= '$user_id' AND date BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH AND CURRENT_DATE";
                    }
                    else if ($period == 'current_second'){
                        $query1 = "SELECT * FROM transaction WHERE account_id ='$acc_id' AND user_id= '$user_id' AND date BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 2 MONTH AND CURRENT_DATE"; 
                    }
                    else {           
                    }

                    $result1 = mysqli_query( $link, $query1 ) or die( mysqli_error( $link ) );
        ?>
                    <?php
                    if ($sort == 'latest'){
                        $query2 = "SELECT * FROM transaction WHERE account_id ='$acc_id' AND user_id= '$user_id' ORDER BY date DESC";
                    }
                    else if ($sort == 'earliest'){
                        $query2 = "SELECT * FROM transaction WHERE account_id ='$acc_id' AND user_id= '$user_id' ORDER BY date ASC";    
                    }
                    else if ($sort == 'codes'){
                        $query2 = "SELECT * FROM transaction WHERE account_id ='$acc_id' AND user_id= '$user_id' ORDER BY transaction_code ASC";
                    }
                    else if ($sort == 'credit'){
                        $query2 = "SELECT * FROM transaction WHERE account_id ='$acc_id' AND user_id= '$user_id' AND debit IS NULL";
                    }

                    else if ($sort == 'debit'){
                        $query2 = "SELECT * FROM transaction WHERE account_id ='$acc_id' AND user_id= '$user_id' AND credit IS NULL";
                    }
                    else {

                    }

                    $result2 = mysqli_query( $link, $query2 ) or die( mysqli_error( $link ) );
                    while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2))
                    {
                        $date1 = $row2['date'];
                        $trans_code = $row2['transaction_code'];
                        $reference = $row2['reference'];
                        $debit = $row2['debit'];
                        $credit = $row2['credit'];

                        $date = new DATETIME($date1);

                    ?>


                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td><?php echo $date->format('d-m-Y'); ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $trans_code ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $reference ?></td>
                            <td>$ <?php echo $debit ?></td>
                            <td>$ <?php echo $credit ?></td>
                            <?php

                    }
                    ?>
```

Comment: right now you're building 2 different queries query1 and query2, what should be done is you build one query and then based on the $sort variable you append the `ORDER BY` portion to the end of query. Also "latest" "earliest" and "codes" should be type "radio" since they can't happen at the same time. "credit" and "debit" should be another radio since they can't happen at the same time either.

Comment: @TinTran Wow, thank you so much! Okay I have edited to a <select> input. How do I run the queries?

Comment: see my answer, you append extra things to query2 using `.=` based on $type and $sort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make your sorting radio buttons, and credit/debit type radio buttons like below

```
            <tr> 
                <td class="alt"><label for="period"><b>Transaction Period:</b> </label></td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="period" value="current">Current Month<br>
                    <input type="radio" name="period" value="current_first">Last 1 Month and Current Month<br>
                    <input type="radio" name="period" value="current_second">Last 2 Months and Current Month</td>          
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="alt"><label for="sort"><b>Sort According To: </b></label></td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="sort" value="latest">Latest Transaction First<br>
                    <input type="radio" name="sort" value="earliest">Earliest Transaction First<br>
                    <input type="radio" name="sort" value="codes">Transaction Codes</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="alt"><label for="type"><b>Credit/Debit Type:</b></label></td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="type" value="both">Credit and Debit<br>
                    <input type="radio" name="type" value="credit">Credit Only<br>
                    <input type="radio" name="type" value="debit">Debit Only </td>        
            </tr>
```

then in your `dotest.php` build your query up based on these values like below

```
$period = $_POST['period'];
$sort = $_POST['sort'];
$type = $_POST['type'];

                if ($period == 'current'){
                    $query2 = "SELECT * FROM transaction WHERE account_id ='$acc_id' AND user_id= '$user_id' AND MONTH(CURDATE())= MONTH(date)";
                }
                elseif ($period == 'current_first'){
                    $query2 = "SELECT * FROM transaction WHERE account_id ='$acc_id' AND user_id= '$user_id' AND date BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH AND CURRENT_DATE";
                }
                else if ($period == 'current_second'){
                    $query2 = "SELECT * FROM transaction WHERE account_id ='$acc_id' AND user_id= '$user_id' AND date BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 2 MONTH AND CURRENT_DATE"; 
                }

                if ($type == 'credit'){
                    $query2 .= " AND debit IS NULL";
                }
                else if ($type == 'debit'){
                    $query2 .= " AND credit IS NULL";
                }

                if ($sort == 'latest'){
                    $query2 .= " ORDER BY date DESC";
                }
                else if ($sort == 'earliest'){
                    $query2 .= " ORDER BY date ASC";    
                }
                else if ($sort == 'codes'){
                    $query2 .= " ORDER BY transaction_code ASC";
                }
```

that way you only execute one query (query2) that does all of the options you wanted.

Comment: Hey I've run this and this error was given "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ORDER BY date DESC' at line 1"